# Get elements from a table with header for each row using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get elements from a table that has header for each row. It is something like this:

```html
<table>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Test name</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>....contents(multiple rows of marks for a candidate)........ </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Test name</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>....contents(multiple rows of marks for a candidate)........ </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Test name</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>....contents(multiple rows of marks for a candidate)........ </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</table>
```

So basically each row of the main table is a table consisting of multiple rows with its own header. I need to get elements of each row table on click on header. I must do this using vanilla Javascript. I should not use any `jquery` related plugin. That is the requirement. So how can I access each row on clicking the header for that row? At present the `className` for each row is the same. So when I use `getElementsByClassName`, I get multiple times of each row. For eg: if there are five rows then I get 5 times of each rows equaling 25 times on each click. If I use `setAttribute` function then I get the rows only the first time I click the button because I change the `className`. So how should I go about solving this problem?

**getTable.js**

```
th = document.getElementsByTagName('th');


for(let c=0; c < th.length; c++){
    th[c].addEventListener('click',item(c));
}


function item(c){    
    return function(){
        console.log(c);
        sortTable(c);
    }
}

function sortTable(c) {
    let table;
    table = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("the_assessments"));
    for(let j=0; j<table.length; j++) {
        table[j].setAttribute("class","assessment_table");
        console.log(table[j]);
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: I have added the javascript code.

Comment: In the present code I am trying to access the rows. I haven't added the sorting function yet.

Comment: Your html is not valid as it is: tables cannot have table elements as direct children. They need to be placed within a `<tr>` and a `<td>`.

Comment: And having to do this kind of thing in Vanilla JS sounds to me like: "I have been told to re-invent the wheel" ;-) : Of course, it is possible, but does it make sense?

Comment: I suggest you narrow the scope of the question to accessing the rows. Then if you have questions regarding the sorting functionally, ask a brand new question regarding that.

Comment: @cars10m Yes. The child table is inside `<td>`.

Comment: @cars10m Yeah. It is like that but that is the requirement. And I have not programmed much in `Javascript` or worked using `HTML` before. So I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @JonP I have changed the question. I will ask another question for sorting if I have any doubts regarding that after I try it. Right now I need to get the elements.

Comment: Similar to Parsa I haven't got much time at the moment, but try looking in the direction of `baseElement.querySelector(selectors)` for selecting your table rows belonging to a particular sub table. ... And: your html has improved, but you still need to wrap the top level `<td>`s in a further `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filled your table structure with a little data to demonstrate how the (ascending) table sorting operation could be done in **Vanilla JavaScript**:

```js
// get the three sub-tables:
var sortdir=-1,i,
    tbls=document.querySelectorAll('table table');
for (var i=0;i<tbls.length;i++) {
// get all rows from each sub-table and dismiss the first (=header) row:
// ( Array.prototype.slice is used to generate an Array from the collection element)
var rows=Array.prototype.slice.call(tbls[i].querySelectorAll('table tr'),1)
// sort by points in third column:
rows.sort((a,b)=>(a.querySelectorAll('td')[2].textContent
                 -b.querySelectorAll('td')[2].textContent)*sortdir);
// apply the order to the sub-table:
for (var j=0;j<rows.length;j++) tbls[i].appendChild(rows[j]);
}
```

```css
td, th {vertical-align:top;text-align:left}
```

```html
<table><tr>
        <td>
           <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Harry</td><td>Potter</td><td>87</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Hermiony</td><td>Granger</td><td>93</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Ron</td><td>Weasley</td><td>78</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Neville</td><td>Longbottom</td><td>57</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Draco</td><td>Malfoy</td><td>86</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Kevin</td><td>Bletchley</td><td>77</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Pansy</td><td>Parkinson</td><td>82</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Points</th>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>Tamsin</td><td>Applebee</td><td>36</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Anthony</td><td>Otterburn</td><td>69</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Diego</td><td>Caplan</td><td>76</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
</tr></table>
```

The three sub-tables containing Hogwart house members are sorted according to their points in column 3.

**Please note** the fact that `appendChild()` does not really "add" a DOM element to a table structure but "moves" it instead!

**Edit "sorting order":**

I added the global variable `sortdir` to demonstrate how to invert the
sorting order. With a negative value the search order is now descending.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. I wrote a code snippet to sort a basic table in ascending order but I am not able to figure out how to sort the same table in descending order on header click. I will open another question.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName(“something”)[0], this will get only the first collection and not every single element with the class of “something”,

Finally for sorting it, I guess you can use some sorted build in function for it, all you need to do is to use an array or list or... to store the values and after sorting it, replace it with the original.

Sorry for not giving any code, I remember I’ve done it a long time ago and i’m in bed ready to sleep!